# Azure Function axios POST empty Response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, azure-functions

I am trying to make an axios call in my React frontend to get some information from the backend to access some information. When I log the response on the server, I see the required information, but in the axios call, I get `data = ""`  for some reason.

ReactJS Axios call

```
await axios
      .post(url, {
        token: this.props.authUser.idToken.rawIdToken,
        blob_path: blobPath,
        container: container
      },
        config
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.data == ""){
        console.log("nada");
        debugger;
        }
        callback(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        debugger;
        callback(error);
      });
```

Azure Server Response Code

```
exit = (result) => {
        console.log("---------- RESULT ------------");
        console.log(result);
        console.log("------ END RESULT ------------");
        context.res = {
            status: 200 /* Defaults to 200 */,
            body: result,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        };
        context.done();
    };
```

The response on the backend

[image]

The response on the frontend

[image]

EDIT: Axios is sending double requests and the old request's response gets ignored.

Comment: Hi. Since you have called `then` after the Promise function, I suggest you remove `await`.

Comment: the actual problem is that we have a React component being mounted multiple times, which calls this axios request multiple times.